# Why does AVPlayer doesn't orient video correctly when using SceneKit?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, scenekit

I'm making a video player in `SceneKit` using both `AVPlayer` and `SCNNode`. Basically, I'm creating an `AVPlayer` using a video URL, set the player into `SCNPlane`'s diffuse contents, create an `SCNNode` using the plane as the geometry, and finally add the node into my `SCNView`'s `rootNode`. Here's the logic that I'm using:

```
private func setupVideoNode() {
        videoPlayer = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
        let videoTrack = videoPlayer!.currentItem!.asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first!
        let naturalSize = videoTrack.naturalSize
        let aspectRatio: CGFloat = CGFloat(naturalSize.width / naturalSize.height) * 10
        
        let videoPlane = SCNPlane(width: aspectRatio, height: 10)
        videoPlane.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
        videoPlane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = videoPlayer
        videoNode = SCNNode(geometry: videoPlane)
        
        sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(videoNode!)
    }
```

Unfortunately, the result looks like this:

[image: The video node WITHOUT preferredTransform applied]

As you can see here, the video is not being oriented correctly (it's rotated to landscape like this instead of the original orientation which is portrait). I tried to apply the `preferredTransform` to calculate the width and height of the video like this:

```
...
let naturalSize = videoTrack.naturalSize
let naturalSizeWithPreferredTransform = naturalSize.applying(videoTrack.preferredTransform)
let aspectRatio: CGFloat = CGFloat(naturalSizeWithPreferredTransform.width / naturalSizeWithPreferredTransform.height) * 10
...
```

But the result looks like this:

[image: The video node WITH preferredTransform applied]

Is there anyway to orient the `AVPlayer` correctly when using `SceneKit` like my specific use case? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.